# Hypothesis testing using Pearson's correlation is giving me the wrong hypothesis.

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, correlation, p-value

Say I have the two hypotheses:

- H0: there is no linear relationship between the two variables.
- H1: there is a linear relationship between the two variables.

Now, my significance level is 0.05, and I have used Pearson's correlation coefficient to calculate the p-value for my two variables (shown below).

```
(-0.19047068210886346, 4.588168807135144e-138)
```

As you can see, my coefficient is -0.19 and my p-value is 4.6.

Therefore, as my p-value is > 0.05, does this mean I have to accept H0, that there is no linear relationship between the two variables?

Though, my correlation coefficient is -0.19, which indicates a very weak linear relationship, so how do I prove this with my hypothesis test?

What has gone wrong? There clearly is a linear relationship here, but the hypothesis test says otherwise.

Comment: The test statistic for your two$-$tailed hypothesis test is $t=r\sqrt{\frac{n-2}{1-r^2}}$ with $n-2$ degrees is freedom. What is your sample size?

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply. I am using Python to calculate this, using a dataset that has over 3,000 rows. Hence, my two variables are both numeric.

Comment: If I'm reading this correctly, your "4.6" is actually basically 0? That's $4.6 \times 10^{-138}$.

Comment: I was just going to say this! The $e-138$ means $10^{-138}$ so your $p-$value is wicked small

Comment: @PatrickStevens - Oh, I misread that! You are correct there!

Comment: Also, since your $t-$score is around $-10.596$ your $p-$value is $$2P(T\leq-10.596)\approx 0$$ where $T$ is a random variable possessing a student's $t-$ distribution having $2998$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Thanks for that. So this means that 4.588168807135144e-138 is less than 0.05?

Comment: Yes. That $e-138$ is indicating scientific notation.

Comment: I see - so, as my value is in the form of a scientific notation, is there a way to see how many zeros are in front of the actual value? Apologies, if I am not making sense.

Comment: Your $p-$value is $4.588168807135144 \times 10^{-138}$ so there are $137$ zeroes in front of the actual value. For example, $5.97\times 10^{-8}$ in standard notation is $0.0000000597$

Comment: Perfect! That makes more sense now. Thank you very much @MatthewPilling for your help today. This has solved my problem with regard to my hypothesis testing. Have a nice day!